# How do I make a function return a value to be used immediately as part of the calling script?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to make a function that I can wrap around certain things and change the output based on the current user.

Assume there is a master user called "av". If the person currently using the DB is "av", then I need to alter the VBA code to allow him better priveleges.

```
Public Function masteruser(input_parm)

   If GetUser = "av" Then

       masteruser = ""

   Else

       masteruser = input_parm

End Function
```

I plan on using the function above like this:

```
Public Sub blah_FormTimer()

   'rest of code

    masteruser(Application.Quit)

    'rest of code

End Sub
```

In the sub above, if the current user is "av", then the `Application.Quit` will effectively be removed. If not, then the code reads `Application.Quit` like normal.

How do I handle the input parameter in such a way as to return it to work with the rest of the VBA script like normal?

Answer (score 0):

You can first create a wrapper sub/function, because `Application.Quit` is a method call and not a function call:

```
Public Sub QuitApplication()
    Application.Quit
End Sub
```

And then use the following code:

```
Public Function masteruser(input_parm As String)
   If GetUser = "av" Then
       masteruser = ""
   Else
       Application.Run input_parm
   End If
End Function
```

And of course

```
Public Sub blah_FormTimer()

   'rest of code

    masteruser "QuitApplication"

    'rest of code

End Sub
```

You can of course create a function that creates a module, creates a wrapper sub/function, then pastes the code that you pass it in that function and executes it, and then deletes that module, but I wouldn't suggest it.

You can also make one especially for method calls, which would prevent the need for making wrapper functions for them:

```
Public Function masterusermethod(objObject as object, strMethod As String)
   If GetUser = "av" Then
       masteruser = ""
   Else
       CallByName objObject, strMethod, VbMethod
   End If
End Function
```

(If anyone knows a more efficient way to do this, I'd like to know)

Comment: How would I use your 4th code block? `masterusermethod()` <-- what arguments would I pass in for `Application.Quit`, for example?

Comment: `masterusermethod(Application, "Quit")` (first the object where you want to call a method on as an object, then the method as a string)

Comment: Is there any way to make this more versatile? I'm looking for something that can be wrapped around almost anything (all the code within a sub block, a single variable's declaration/assignment, etc...), i.e. not necessarily only for method calls. I envisioned a `masteruser` function that lets me literally blank out parts of the code if necessary (i.e. if the user is "av"), but if it's not necessary then it should act as though the arguments that get passed are unaffected by this wrapping function.

Comment: Well, then you're in the area of creating a module on the fly with a function inside that module, and then running a function. I can (probably, never tried but have created modules with VBA) show you how to do that, but it has serious drawbacks, such as lower performance and requiring an exclusive lock on the database. And the code will still have to be in a string, and you still won't have access to your local variables. A way more appropriate option is just use GoTo statements, because they kinda do exactly what you described.

Comment: Oh! You might be onto something! I never even thought of that!!